# Unexpected end of regex when ascii character

Tags: c++, regex

Minimal Verfiable Example

```
  #include<regex>
  int main(){
   std::regex re("\\u_nic400_ib_ext_m_ib_ar_fifo_wr_mux/mux_0_1_out [0]");

    }
```

Why is this giving me a regex_error? My debugger's error message is unexpected end of regex when ascii character, but I just trying to match the literal above and I don't see where the issue is.

Comment: `\u` is an escape sequence for matching a Unicode code point.

Comment: If you want to match a literal backslash, use ```\\\\```

Comment: @Barmar your first comment is the answer I think. Did not know that.

Comment: Why are you using a regex if you just want to match a literal string?

Comment: @Barmar because the code that is using that regex doesn't necessarily match a literal string. It generates the regex at run time.

Comment: It is stronly recommended to use raw string literals with regular expressions.

Comment: @n.m Is there a function that will convert a std::string to raw string to create the regex at run time? I tried searching for one but couldn't find one.

Comment: `[0]` is a character range of a single `0` character, so probably not what you intended.  It will need escaping as well.

Comment: @AJNeufeld is there a standard library function that will force the regex engine to see this as a raw string or add the escape sequences automatically? I can ask this as a seperate question if necessary.

Comment: Well, that's an embarrassing error message: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/fbd263526ad105a953fd51d9f7bca2c3f268cf82/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/regex_scanner.tcc#L355-L368. The verb is missing, we haven't reached the end of the regex, and what does `\u` have to do with ASCII characters?

Comment: @user3586940 Raw strings are only a source code concept, it only matters for literals. If you're constructing the string dynamically, it's not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\u` is the beginning of the escape sequence for a Unicode code point, you need to escape it. Also, `[...]` is a character set match, it needs to be escaped if you want to match it literally.

```
std::regex re("\\\\u_nic400_ib_ext_m_ib_ar_fifo_wr_mux/mux_0_1_out \\[0\\]");
```

If you're using C++11 or newer, it's helpful to use raw strings when writing regular expressions, so you don't have to double the backslashes.

```
std::regex re(R"(\\u_nic400_ib_ext_m_ib_ar_fifo_wr_mux/mux_0_1_out \[0\])");
```

This is all only relevant if you're creating the regexp as a literal. If you're constructing it dynamically at run time, you don't need to double the escapes, since you're feeding the string directly to the regexp engine, it's not being parsed as C source code.